# Is possible to suggest a string in a Console input? (java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'd like to read a string from the Console (e.g. using the Scanner class) but I would like to have an already existing string as modifiable suggestion.

As example, immagine that I have an old string name that I want to modify at running time but I would like the old string would be suggested as a ready-to-modify string.

Let's say:

```
String oldString = "old string to change";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String new = ???
```

Is it possible? 
Thanks

Comment: *Almost* anything is possible when you write code.

Comment: Why don't you write something and then may be we can try to help!

Comment: @Marco What are you getting as input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that when reading `System.in`.

You'd have to write a Swing UI and your own console window to have functionality like that.

The common practice for supplying a default value (non-editable) is to show it in the prompt, and use that default if user just presses enter.

E.g.

```
Enter first name [John]:
Enter last name [Doe]: Smith
Hello, John Smith
```

If the default value is long and the user wants to modify it, the user can easily copy/paste it.